# Openbr python wrapper from command line

Tags: python, cmd, openbr

i'm trying to execute this file test.py from command line:

```
from brpy import init_brpy
import requests # or whatever http request lib you prefer
import MagicalImageURLGenerator # made up



# br_loc is /usr/local/lib by default,
# you may change this by passing a different path to the shared objects

br = init_brpy(br_loc='/path/to/libopenbr')
br.br_initialize_default()
br.br_set_property('algorithm','CatFaceRecognitionModel') # also made up
br.br_set_property('enrollAll','true')

mycatsimg = open('mycats.jpg', 'rb').read() # cat picture not provided =^..^=
mycatstmpl = br.br_load_img(mycatsimg, len(mycatsimg))
query = br.br_enroll_template(mycatstmpl)
nqueries = br.br_num_templates(query)

scores = []
for imurl in MagicalImageURLGenerator():
# load and enroll image from URL
img = requests.get(imurl).content
tmpl = br.br_load_img(img, len(img))
targets = br.br_enroll_template(tmpl)
ntargets = br.br_num_templates(targets)

# compare and collect scores
scoresmat = br.br_compare_template_lists(targets, query)
for r in range(ntargets):
    for c in range(nqueries):
        scores.append((imurl, br.br_get_matrix_output_at(scoresmat, r, c)))

# clean up - no memory leaks
br.br_free_template(tmpl)
br.br_free_template_list(targets)

# print top 10 match URLs
scores.sort(key=lambda s: s[1])

for s in scores[:10]:
print(s[0])

# clean up - no memory leaks
br.br_free_template(mycatstmpl)
br.br_free_template_list(query)
br.br_finalize()
```

this script file is /myfolder/ while the library brpy is in /myfolder/scripts/brpy.

The brpy folder contains 3 files: "face_cluster_viz.py" , "html_viz.py" and "**init**.py" .

When i try to execute this file from cmd it shows an error:

> NameError; name 'init_brpy' is not defined

Why? Where am I doing wrong? Is it possible execute this script from command line?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following line:

```
br = init_brpy(br_loc='/path/to/libopenbr')
```

You have to set your path of the openbr library.